# Proving a combinatoric proof using the result of $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk\ (-1)^k = 0$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, binomial-theorem

so I am supposed to solve a proof which seems fairly easy, but the negative exponents in $$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk\ (\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1})= \frac{1}{n+1}$$ are making this question very difficult for me. I have tried using binomial theorem on the right side with $(n+1)^{-1}$ but I understand that operation does not make sense. I can also tell that the only difference between the two proofs is that the left side has an additional $(k+1)^{-1}$ and the right side has an additional $(n+1)^{-1}$, but I am still having difficulty solving this question. Hints appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\binom{n}{k} / (k+1)  = \binom{n+1}{k+1} / (n+1)$

Comment: @JWL is this an identity? thank you.

Comment: okay, using that identity i have solved it. thanks

Comment: I found a [combinatorial argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490583/find-the-value-of-sum-0n-binomnk-1k-frac1k1/1492708#1492708) for you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider antidifferentiating $f(x)=(1-x)^n$.

Comment: I am not at the level where I have learned integration.

Comment: No integration here. Just differentiating in reverse.

Comment: I have not learned antidifferentiation as well. The only knowledge I have of calculus barely reaches differentiation.

Comment: Well, then this approach is going to be a bit more difficult.

Comment: @Arthur I actually don't see what to do. You get $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}(-1)^k \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} = -\frac{1}{n+1}(1-x)^{n+1}$. Now what value of $x$ do you plug in?

Comment: @matgworker21 You plug in $x=1$, since that makes the terms in the sum what we want them to be. However, you've committed one of the classic mistakes: You didn't pay enough attention to the constant term of the antiderivative.

Answer (score 0):

The binomial theorem gives:
$$(1-x)^n= \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k x^k$$
Integrate w.r.t. x both sides from $x=0$ to $x=1$, to get
$$\left .\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k  {n \choose k}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} \right|_{0}^{1}= -\left.\frac{(1-x)^{n+1}}{n+1} \right|_{0}^{1}=\frac{1}{n+1}.$$

Comment: I don't know if you noticed my answer and the comments below it, but this doesn't seem to be an approach that the OP is after, or even understands.